# Dependency Injection Abstraction Library

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Is there anything like 
https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection for good old .NET framework applications?

"Contains common DI abstractions that ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core use."

I am writing a framework and I do not want to force a specific IoC container on users.

Comment: You can use a `.NET Core` project that consumes the **DI** packages, and then have this project target the full framework.

Comment: I'm going to give this a try. Can you please change your comment to answer, so that I might accept it if I manage to make it work? I could also use some help in adding such a project into an existing 4.6.2 solution.

Comment: Prevent having a [common DI abstraction](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/) at all; make your framework [DI friendly](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/).

Comment: @Steven, thanks for your comment. I read that article, I am aware that that would be the "formally correct" way. I'm drawing the line, however, between productivity and correctness, and willing to pursue the former. I'd also argue that ASP.NET vNext uses a DI abstraction, and I'd like to provide a familiar experience to whomever uses that technology (including myself). My framework is a convention-based application server that should expose both queue-based and http-based endpoints without forcing a specific technology on developers.

Comment: @Raine: You should not do the same as ASP.NET Core does with their DI abstraction. They made a huge mistake in creating their abstraction, since almost none of the DI library maintainers is able to create a compatible adapter on top of that abstraction (including Autofac and Simple Injector). For the next release of ASP.NET Core (v1.1) Microsoft has promised to improve integration scenarios in the same way as Mark Seemann proposed in the blog posts I referred to. So copying their DI abstraction is a really bad idea.

Comment: @Steven, interesting, can you point me to the article that states they are going to improve such integration scenarios?

Comment: @Raine: Absolutely. This [this discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/pull/416) between maintainers and Microsoft.

Comment: @Steven, I'm scanning the discussion (thanks for the link, appreciated), but are we sure the core issue is DI abstraction or the fact that they are relying on service registration order and other out-of-band information (the horror)? I need to expose extensibility points that let consumers register services with a specific lifetime. I hate the proliferation of factories, whereas a DI container is, at its core, a generic object factory.

Comment: @Raine: Yes, the core issue is the DI abstraction. If you read the thread, you'll see that even the Autofac maintainers acknowledge this.

Comment: @Steven please add an answer with the links and motivation as to why this is a bad idea, I'd be glad to accept it as an answer given the current state of affairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am writing a framework and I do not want to force a specific IoC container on users.

The way to do that is to create good extension points for users to replace. Having a common DI abstraction is a bad idea, because this is an anti-pattern called [Conforming Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/). This anti-pattern is not something theoretical; ASP.NET Core applies this anti-pattern and the result of this is that both the Simple Injector maintainers AND the Autofac Maintainers were unable to create an adapter implementation that fully complies with the defined contract. The Simple Injector story can be read [here](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2016/06/whats-wrong-with-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/) and [here](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2016/07/working-around-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/) and a general discussion with Microsoft about this can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/pull/416). You can read my open letter to Microsoft in this thread [here](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/pull/416#issuecomment-231736332) and you can see that the Autofac maintainers [agree](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/pull/416#issuecomment-231773011) with this statement.

In the end, Microsoft [acknowledged](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/pull/416#issuecomment-231806385) the problems by promising that they will build a good integration possibilities by providing

> adequate composition roots per framework to make integration as smooth as it can be.

So prevent applying the Conforming Container anti-pattern in your own framework. We already see Microsoft fixing the problems that this anti-pattern has caused in the next minor release of ASP.NET Core. Instead do provide "good integration possibilities" as Mark Seemann described [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/).

Comment: Thank you for your time, Steven. Given the state of apparent uncertainty (development-wise) of asp.net core and .net core, I might be better off erring on the side of caution instead of imitating the current asp.net core version. I can also appreciate the good points in the articles you provided. I am still unsure as to how balance productivity vs. correctness in this particular instance, but I guess that comes with the territory :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `.NET Core` project that consumes the **DI** packages, and then have this project target the full framework. You'd target one of the "full" target framework monikers (TFM), and you're `project.json` would look something like this:

```
{      
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": { }
  },

  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

Comment: Tried a few combinations and some refactoring but it seems it's not easy to have a .net core library within a .NET 4.6.2 solution. Might be me, though!